# Half of normal mapped object is inverted

Tags: c++, 3d, glsl, vulkan

I have tried to implement normal mapping for 3 days now in vulkan. I pre-calculate the tangents and bitangents in the simple obj loader i made and create the TBN matrix in the shader. For now I'm just trying to get it to work, optimizations is saved for later. I'm very confused for why this problem occurs, I have googled around a lot which led me to check for handedness in the texture coordinates. This hasn't solved my problem though. I'm not sure what could be the problem or why this doesn't look correct. I worked with openGL before and this problem also occurred then. The normal mapping works on another model, but not this one.

**Example of the problem**
[image]

This is how i pre-calculate the tangents and bitangents

```
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i += 3)
            {
                Vector3f deltapos1 = vertices[i + 1].position - vertices[i].position;
                Vector3f deltapos2 = vertices[i + 2].position - vertices[i].position;

                Vector2f deltauv1 = vertices[i + 1].uv - vertices[i].uv;
                Vector2f deltauv2 = vertices[i + 2].uv - vertices[i].uv;

                float f;

                Vector3f tangent(1, 0, 0);
                Vector3f bitangent(0, 1, 0);

                float det = deltauv1.x * deltauv2.y - deltauv1.y * deltauv2.x;

                if (det != 0)
                {
                    f = 1.0f / det;

                    tangent = (deltapos1 * deltauv2.y - deltapos2 * deltauv1.y) * f;
                    bitangent = (deltapos2 * deltauv1.x - deltapos1 * deltauv2.x) * f;
                }

                vertices[i].tangent     = tangent;
                vertices[i + 1].tangent = tangent;
                vertices[i + 2].tangent = tangent;

                vertices[i].bitangent     = bitangent;
                vertices[i + 1].bitangent = bitangent;
                vertices[i + 2].bitangent = bitangent;
            }

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
            {
                vertices[i].tangent = Math::normalize(vertices[i].tangent - vertices[i].normal * Math::dot(vertices[i].tangent, vertices[i].normal));

                if (Math::dot(Math::cross(vertices[i].bitangent, vertices[i].tangent), vertices[i].normal) < 0.0f)
                    vertices[i].bitangent = Math::normalize(Math::cross(vertices[i].normal, vertices[i].tangent)) * -1;
                else
                vertices[i].bitangent = 
                Math::normalize(Math::cross(vertices[i].normal, vertices[i].tangent));

            }
```

Vertex shader

```
void main()
{
    UV = vec2(inUv.x, 1.0f - inUv.y);

    mat3 nmat = mat3(((ubo.model)));

    gl_Position =  ubo.mvp * vec4(inPosition, 1.0f);

    Normal = normalize(nmat * inNormal); 
    vec3 T = normalize(nmat * inTangent);
    vec3 B = normalize(nmat * inBitangent);
    vec3 N = Normal;

    //T = normalize(T - N * dot(T, N));
    //B = normalize(cross(T, N));

    mat3 TBN = mat3(T, B, N);

    toModelSpace = TBN;

    fragPos = vec3(ubo.model * vec4(inPosition, 1.0f));
    viewPos = ubo.cameraPos;
```

This is how I convert normal map to model space

```
vec3 normal = normalize(texture(imageBump, UV).rgb * 2.0f - 1.0f);
normal = normalize(toModelSpace * normal);
```

Comment: Are you missing an "else" in your handedness check?  The reason that I ask is that you are overwriting the value of "vertices[i].bitangent" after you perform your check.

Comment: Did not notice that, thanks. But now the normals looks inverted for some reason.

Comment: Do they look uniformly inverted?  Or, do you still have the seam?

Comment: the edges looks dark when the light direction is pointing to it, and with an other model half of it is inverted

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) You are inverting the bitangent ~ should it be the tangent?  2) Should the handedness check be done in the shader?

Comment: inverting the tangent instead makes it look inverted. But why should handedness be done in shader though, I'm not changing the tangents or bitangents after.

Comment: Got it.  Just brainstorming.

Comment: What I don't understand though is that I use another model, and the normal mapping looks correct. I have tried replacing the current sponza model with another one, but it doesn't change anything. I have checked other sources for the calculation of tangents and bitangents, also handedness, but still not getting same results.

Comment: I ran across this: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-13-normal-mapping/#handedness  Their implementation is different from yours ~ they use dot(cross(n, t), b) and invert t.  However, you may have already tried that.

Comment: yes i have tried that, many different sources uses different calculations. Since already did this around 1.5 years ago in OpenGL I have checked many different sources. This time in vulkan, I get same results. Feels like maybe its the models problem. I will check for another one, since the other model(helmet) looks correct.

Comment: seems like that is not the problem